# Mount a "multi-level" JSON Object from a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest

I need some help with a Rails Project. I need to mount a multi level JSON with a structure like this (a lot bigger than this lol):

```
{"totalAmount" => 0,
  "paymentInfo" => {
    "transactionType" => {
      "something" => 10
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get it using a form_tag, but I can't get the object inside the object from it. How can I do it the right way? I'm going to pass this JSON to a Rest Service via HTTParty

my form so far

```
<%= form_tag '/sendPayment',{method: :post} do %>
<div>
  <%= label_tag 'Total Amount' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'totalAmount' %>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
  <%= label_tag 'Transaction Type' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'paymentInfo[transactionType]' %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= label_tag 'something' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'paymentInfo[transactionType][something]' %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My Controller

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
require 'digest'


class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def sendPayment
   puts params

   @jsonParams = params.to_json
   puts @jsonParams
   @result = HTTParty.post('http://public-api-elb-1090807689.us-west-     2.elb.amazonaws.com/v1/sync/payments'.to_str,
  :body => @jsonParams.to_json,
  :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )

puts @result
 end

end
```

Comment: Post your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, Please update the question with one more level

Comment: I update the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```rb
<%= form_tag '/someroute',{method: :post, format: :json} do %>
  <%= number_field_tag 'totalAmount', '0',{class:'form-control',min:0} %>
  <%= select_tag 'paymentInfo[transactionType]', options_for_select(['Paypal','Bitcoin','CC'],'Paypal'),{class:'form-control'} %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Pay!' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That work with one level, but i can't do it with two, like:

    <%= text_field_tag 'paymentInfo[transactionType[something]]' %>

Is There a way to do this?

Comment: Use `<%= text_field_tag 'paymentInfo[transactionType][something]' %>` instead (Note the change in the brackets).

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried that exactly and it works fine.  *Note: I just saw your updated question. Take into account that you cannot set `paymentInfo[transactionType]` to a text_field, and at the same time have `paymentInfo[transactionType][something]`. That's not a valid JSON*